# Python Argparse Cant Split string

Tags: python, split, argparse

This should be simple.  But it is really getting to me now.  I have setup a simple argparse and want to be able to split a string if it has a minus symbol.  Sounds simple but when items are parsed into argparse it comes up blank.  So I will show you what I want to do and why it is puzzling me.  Note: I have hard specified it as a string. The dir and type functions come up blank.

```
        import argparse
        import sys
        portlist = []

        #Parser Arguments and Usage
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This script performs a Syn scan on a specific host with the ports that are specified by you.', usage='Specify Ports with the -p switch. Port range -p 80-200, specific port -p 80, multiple ports -p 80,443,25,22', add_help=True) 
        parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', dest='argPorts', help='Type ports in like follows.  For a range -p 80-200, for a group of ports -p 443,80,25,22 or single port -p 80', required=True, type=str) 
        parser.add_argument('-d', action='store', dest='destIP', help='Type dest IP in this field.  i.e. 192.168.0.5', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='threadCount', help='Type the amount of threads to use as an integer', type=int, required=True)

        if len(sys.argv)<3:
            parser.print_help()
                sys.exit(0)
        opts = vars(parser.parse_args())

        options = parser.parse_args()
        argPorts = options.argPorts
        destIP = options.destIP
        threadCount = options.threadCount

        if argPorts.find(','):
            print "comma"
            for p in argPorts.split(','):
                portlist.append(p)

        elif argPorts.find('-'):
            print "range"
            portlist.append(argPorts.split('-')[0])
            portlist.append(argPorts.split('-')[1])

        else:
            print "no"


        print portlist
```

I am using the command line as follows.
python test.py -t 10 -p "80-100" -d "192.168.136.131"

I am wanting to be able to split 80 and 100 to separate variables. But it doesnt work :(

Answer below is great.

Here is a good explanation for other people like me http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-see-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-python/

Comment: Omg thankyou so much.  It has been killing my life.  Mind you I am still learning python.

Comment: The title is misleading - the problem occurs in the processing of the strings AFTER `argparse` is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is, that .find() return a -1, if the searchstring was not found. So you can't check this only by existence.

you can try something like this:

```
if argPorts.find(',') != -1:
    ...
elif argPorts.find('-') != -1:
    ...
```

I would prefer something like this:

```
if ',' in argPorts:
    print("comma")
    for p in argPorts.split(','):
        portlist.append(p)
elif '-' in argPorts:
    print("range")
    portlist.append(argPorts.split('-')[0])
    portlist.append(argPorts.split('-')[1])
else:
    print("no")
```

Additional. I think, you want to create a list of ports, if a range is given.

```
for port in range(int(argPorts.split('-')[0]), int(argPorts.split('-')[1])+1):
    portlist.append(port)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the port parsing logic into a function and pass it as a `type` to your `add_argument('-p')`, and add some user-friendly exceptions like so

```
def parse_port(port):
    if port.isdigit():
        return int(port)
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                "'{}' is not a valid port".format(port))

def parse_port_range(port_range):
    range_members = port_range.split("-")
    if len(range_members) != 2:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                "'{}' is not a valid port range".format(port_range))
    actual_range = range(parse_port(range_members[0]),
                         parse_port(range_members[1]) + 1)
    return actual_range

def parse_ports(port_string):
    #first break commas
    port_groups = port_string
    if ',' in port_string:
        port_groups = port_string.split(",")            

    #then figure out ranges and populate the set of ports
    ports = set()
    for port_group in port_groups:
        if "-" in port_group:
            port_range = parse_port_range(port_group)
            ports.update(port_range)
        else: # single port
            ports.add(parse_port(port_group))
    return list(ports)

#finally create your CLI argument
parser.add_argument('-p', dest='argPorts', type=parse_ports,
                    help=('Type ports in like follows.  For a range -p 80-200, '
                          'for a group of ports -p 443,80-200,25,22 or single '
                          'port -p 80'))
```

After you `parser.parse_args()`, your `options.argPorts` contains a list of integer ports, and if the port input is erroneous the user gets a helpful message.